# Pandas - Merging on multi-index both ways

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes: `df1` and `df2`. Both have two indices, `A` and `B`. I can easily join them on their indices by doing `pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index = True, right_index = True, how = 'left')`. However, I want to not only merge `df1`'s `A, B` on `df2`'s `A, B`, but I also want to merge `df1`'s `B, A` on `df2`'s `A, B` (flipping the index order for `df1`).

Is there a simple way to do this? I want to merge on the indices for performance reasons.

Comment: Can the value in A also be in B? What do you want to have happen for these combinations of A, B: `('x', 'y'), ('y', 'x'), ('x','x')` in all in both df1 and df2?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understood correctly, but can't you do this?

```
#first merge
pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'left', left_on=['A', 'B'], right_on=['A', 'B'])
#second merge
pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'left', left_on=['B', 'A'], right_on=['A', 'B'])
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to do it on the index.

Comment: you temporarily reset index using `.reset_index(drop=False)` to use in your merge

Comment: I was just actually able to do it by doing df1.index = df1.index.swaplevel(0,1)

Comment: yeah, that's a much cleaner way, glad you figured it out!